# JQuery UI: How to remove Icon from specific Accordion group?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I would like to remove the icon from a specific group in my JQuery UI Accordion, but the icons seem to be set in a quite difficult way in the JS.
I figured that using `"icons : false"` inside my Jquery-function would turn off the icons for all the groups inside my accordion, but i would like to turn them off only for specific ones (in this case, the last group called "single Section"), is that possible?

```
$(function() {
    $( "#accordion" )
      .accordion({
        header: "> div > h3",
        icons: false

      })
      .sortable({
        axis: "y",
        handle: "h3",
        stop: function( event, ui ) {
          // IE doesn't register the blur when sorting
          // so trigger focusout handlers to remove .ui-state-focus
          ui.item.children( "h3" ).triggerHandler( "focusout" );

          // Refresh accordion to handle new order
          $( this ).accordion( "refresh" );
        }
      });
  });
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k5o7x0pq/1/) to the full code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this via CSS

```
.device .ui-accordion-header-icon {
    display: none !important;
}
```

You can add a class for single accordions group and control via CSS

Comment: Glad that helped you.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it via jquery

$("#accordion").find('.device .ui-accordion-header-icon').hide();